# php - return the value of an ajax post back to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I'm trying to test the successful submission of data from javascript to a php file by having that php file return the results of the javascript post back to javascript. I'm getting a successful response in the ajax post, but the data is an empty string. How do I find out what data was posted? Here's my code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var benefitsArray = ["someData","someOtherData"];

$('#drop-submit').on('click',function(){
if (benefitsArray.length > 0){

    var formData = { "benefits" : benefitsArray };
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url : "dd-receiver.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data); //result is "";
            debugger;
            //data - response from server
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('failure');
        }
    });
}
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST["benefits"]
?>
```

---

UPDATE:

I got a response by, in the php code, doing:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['benefits']);
```

but the problem is that in the javascript, if I log the data, the result is

`"["someData","someOtherData"]"` (a string)

and not

`["someData","someOtherData"]` (an array)

how do I get it to return an array and not a string?

Comment: Does echoing `"Hello World!"` perform any differently?

Comment: Does adding `return false;` at the end of the click function help? Without it, you're probably submitting the form and none of the rest of the function executes.

Comment: BTW, echoing an array will just echo the word "Array", not the contents.

Comment: can you provide the `var_dump($_POST);` output?

Comment: In the Javascript, if you add `dataType: "json"` as an option to `$.ajax`, jQuery will parse the JSON automatically and provide `data` as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing the JSON being sent to you.

You can make jQuery do this for you by adding `dataType: 'JSON'` to your `$.ajax` options...

```
 $.ajax({
   dataType: 'JSON',
   url : "dd-receiver.php",
   type: "POST",
   data : formData,
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ...
```

**Or** manually with `JSON.parse`:

```
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     benefits = JSON.parse(data);
     ...
   }
```